# What does expiration date mean on Visual Studio package updates?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, versioning, package

What happens if I don't update before 04.09.2015 ? Who and how manages those dates?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the expiration date for the message.

If you wait until after that date, the message will go away and you'll need to remember to install the update on your own.